# Erro com parâmetro do tipo variant quando usado atributos

Tags: delphi

Boa noite!
Estou com um problema que acontece ao usar atributos no delphi, tenho o seguinte construtor:

```
constructor Create(Value: Variant; Operacoes: TCompare;
  Referencia: TReferenceCompare; Origem: String; Tipo: TVarType); overload;
```

e no parâmetro Value da a seguinte mensagem de erro:
"Could not convert variant of type (Error) into type (OleStr)".

obs: quando troco este parâmetro por um string funciona perfeitamente, estou chamando ele da seguinte maneira:

[TAtributo('Edit4.Text', tcNotLess, rcObject, 'Text', varInteger)]

A mensagem acontece quando faço a atribuição a uma property da minha classe, estou com dificuldade pois o erro acontece somente quando eu o uso no construtor do atributo customizado, ao criar um método dentro do meu form por exemplo, da certo.
Me deparei com um outro erro ao utilizar RTTI dentro dos métodos da classe do atributo, quando eu declaro a uses RTTI depois do atributo, ele compila, porem não funciona, para funcionar era só declarar antes da declaração da classe. Por isso estou suspeitando de por ser um TCustomAttribute eu tenha que usar de maneira diferente, porem não tenho conhecimento de como fazer isso, alguém poderia me ajudar? Desde já agradeço.
Se alguém poder explicar também, ou sugerir um link onde eu possa entender mais sobre atributos fico grato.